# Explain WolframAlpha output

Tags: real-numbers, wolfram-alpha

I just inputted [(x-10)^2+(y-2)^2 = 5^2, y= k*x+2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-10)%5E2%2B(y-2)%5E2%20%3D%205%5E2,%20y%3D%20k*x%2B2) into the WolframAlpha input text field. Under the section dedicated to 
*Real solutions* it states that $x=\frac{15}{2}$. I do not understand this output, although I do recognise and agree with it.
Can someone please help me understand the output (as in how it found it)?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

**The assignment** is

> A circle has the equation $(x-10)^2+(y-2)^2=5^2$. Line $t$ goes through the point $p(0,2)$ and is tangent to the circle.

Comment: That's just one of the coordinates of the two intersection points you got, no?

Comment: True. But I still don't understand how I can make this assignment with proper arguments.

Comment: You are working too hard for this problem. You might want to recall that a tangent and a radius can be perpendicular.

Comment: But how do I use that information? I know they can, but I am not aware of how to implement it ..

Comment: You've already represented the tangent as $y=kx+2$, no? Then the radius would be (why?) $y-2=-\frac1{k}(x-10)$. The intersection of these two lines is the tangency point on the circle, which should be in terms of $k$. Plug into your circle equation, and solve.

Comment: What should I _plug_ into the circle equation?

Comment: Do you agree that the coordinates of a tangency point ought to satisfy the equation of the associated circle?

Comment: Yes, I do fully agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to find out why:
Tangents to the circle $(x-10)^2+(y-2)^2=5^2$ have the equation $$(x-10)(x_P-10)+(y-2)(y_P-2)=5^2$$
I can insert values for $y_P$ and $x_P$: $$(x-10)(0-10)+(y-2)(2-2)=5^2$$ where the right side equals $0$. Then I isolate for x:
$$-10x+100=25$$
$$-10x+75=0$$
$$75=10x$$
$$\frac{15}{2}=x$$

Comment: If you're allowed to use calculus, implicit differentiation can quickly derive the expression for the tangent line from the circle's equation.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately, I have not yet learned about differentiation, calculus or other higher level stuff. I guess that would also be smart to tag? ;)
I actually just about started Cartesian geometry (in the plane). However, I greatly appreciate your sharing of knowledge. :)

Comment: That's why supplying context is important when asking a question on this site. When I gave you the hint above in the comments, I didn't know that you knew the compact formula for a circle tangent, so I gave you the usual "blind" method to proceed. In any case, you should still try finishing that route, even if only for practice in algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Of course. I will have that in mind next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: solve the equation $$(x-10)^2+(kx+2-2)^2=25$$ for $x$
simplifying you get the following quadratic equation
$$x^2(1+k^2)-20x+75=0$$
can you solve this?
after dividing by $$1+k^2\ne 0$$ we get
$$x^2-\frac{20x}{1+k^2}+\frac{75}{1+k^2}=0$$ we get
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{10}{1+k^2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{10}{1+k^2}\right)^2-\frac{75}{1+k^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not see how to do that.

Comment: ok a few minutes i will help you

Comment: why the $-1$? i don't understand it

Comment: Nope, I can't. Are you able to? :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I do not see how this explains it. :/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking wolfram for which values of $x,y$ and $k$ the equations $(x-10)^2+(y-2)^2 = 5^2$ and $y= kx+2$ are true. These are 2 equations in 3 different variables so there are infinitely many solutions. Under real solutions, wolfram shows you the values of $x,y$ $k$ such that the equations are true and such that $x,y$ and $k$ are real numbers (no complex part, see complex numbers).

Comment: I am aware of the distinction, but how did **it** find it?

Comment: Your question wasn't asking for that...

Comment: I wasn't aware of that but I have rectified it.